# Helper class for accessing blobs and mmap memory

Tags: c++, c++11, array, memory-management, casting

This class was inspired from Microsoft's `array_view`.

It intended to use with `mmap`-ed memory for easily check bounds and so on.

I probably will need to throw exceptions, but this is not my usual way of working.

Any comments are welcome.

```
#include <cstring>

class BlobRef{
public:
    BlobRef(const void *mem, size_t const size) noexcept :
                mem_( (const char *) mem),
                size_(size){}

    // for test purposes
    BlobRef(const char *s) noexcept :
                BlobRef(s, strlen(s) + 1){}

    template<size_t N>
    BlobRef(const char(&mem)[N]) noexcept:
                BlobRef(mem, N){}

public:
    bool empty() const noexcept{
        return mem_ == nullptr || size_ == 0;
    }

    size_t size() const noexcept{
        return size_;
    }

    const void *data_() const noexcept{
        return mem_;
    }

public:
    const void *safeAccessMemory(size_t const pos, size_t const size) const noexcept{
        if (pos + size <= size_)
            return & mem_[pos];
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    template <class T>
    const T *as(size_t const pos = 0, size_t const elements = 1) const noexcept{
        return (const T *) safeAccessMemory(pos, elements * sizeof(T));
    }

private:
    const char  *mem_ = nullptr;
    size_t      size_ = 0;
};


#include <cstdint>
#include <assert.h>
#include <endian.h>

int test_blobref(){
    constexpr size_t SIZE = 256;
    char mem[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        mem[i] = (char) i;

    BlobRef br{ mem };

    assert(*br.as<uint16_t>(0x00) == htobe16(0x0001)    );
    assert(*br.as<uint16_t>(0x0E) == htobe16(0x0E0F)    );
    assert(*br.as<uint32_t>(0x10) == htobe32(0x10111213)    );

    {
        const char *s = br.as<char>('a');
        assert(strncmp(s, "abcde", 5) == 0);
    }

    {
        struct TestStruct{
            uint16_t    i;
            char        c;
            char        s[4];
        }__attribute__((__packed__));

        const TestStruct *st = br.as<TestStruct>(0x50);
        assert(st->i == htobe16(0x5051)     );
        assert(st->c == 0x52            );

        const char *s1 = st->s;
        const char s2[] = { 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57 };
        assert(strncmp(s1, s2, sizeof s2) == 0);
    }

    {
        size_t const pos = SIZE / sizeof(uint64_t);

        const uint64_t *u64 = br.as<uint64_t>(0, pos);
        assert(u64 != nullptr   );
        assert(u64[      0] == htobe64(0x0001020304050607)  );
        assert(u64[pos - 1] == htobe64(0xf8f9fafbFCFDFEFF)  );
    }

    {
        size_t const pos = SIZE / sizeof(uint64_t) ;

        const uint64_t *u64 = br.as<uint64_t>(0, pos + 1 );
        assert(u64 == nullptr   );
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    test_blobref();
}
```

Comment: You have a big flaw there. Why would you use strlen if you're sure if the memory given is not string? strlen counts only until 0, so the code contains UB

Comment: testing purposes with C strings. not intended to be used in "real" code. but yes, I missed +1. FIXED. I doubt I'll ever need templated constructor as well.

Comment: "not intended to be used in "real" code". Does it work? Have you tried it? Does the compiler even want to compile it? Is the output as expected?

Comment: yes, cstring constructor works. BlobRef br{ "hello" }; will execute it and will create 6 bytes blob. I guess it will be useful for patter matching.

Comment: You may want to read up on [Alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### BlobRef details

- You should provide a default constructor.
- `safeAccessMemory` contains a bug. If you have an empty `BlobRef` and you call `safeAccessMemory(0, 0)` you will deference a nullptr (the guard fails).
- Don't use c-style casts. In your cases you should use `reinterpret_cast`. This helps readability, search-ability and signals clear intent.
- `as` can invoke undefined behaviour if called on certain types. The gritty details are in 3.10.10 of the C++ spec.

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> the dynamic type of the object.
>
> a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object.
>
> a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object.
>
> a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object.
>
> a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object.
>
> an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union), a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object.
>
> a char or unsigned char type.

My understand is that there's no easy way to make this work ([the gsl folks removed theirs](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/153))

Unfortunately this would remove the entire essence of this class. One approach you could take to remedy this would be to use type-traits to restrict the function to types for which it will be well defined.

```
template <class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
const T *as(size_t const pos = 0, size_t const elements = 1) const noexcept{
    return (const T *) safeAccessMemory(pos, elements * sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate why I need default constructor? this is not Java :)

Comment: i "fixed" as() with static_assert + is_pod

Comment: @Nick Having a default constructor will make working with the STL containers/algorithms more painless amongst other reasons.

Comment: yes, I added the class to my "bigger" class and already noticed it ;)

Comment: follow up: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141162/helper-class-for-accessing-blobs-and-mmap-memory-follow-up